# Thread stuck because having a never ending function in run

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a myThread Class

Note : I'm using Log.d to display text (Android)

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {
    public MyThread() {
        Log.d(logtag,"init"); 
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.d(logtag,"run"); 

        neverEndingFunction();

    @Override
    public void interrupt() {
        super.interrupt();

        stopNeverEndingFunction();

     }
```

In my main, I simply did

```
my_thread = new MyThread();
my_thread.run();    
Log.d(logtag,"Hello");
```

But the problem is my "Hello" is never displayed because it's stuck in the neverEndingFunction.

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you start a thread using [**Thread#start()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29) method not **Thread#run**.

change your code to below:

```
my_thread = new MyThread();
my_thread.start();
```

**[Thread#start()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29)** will

> Causes this thread to begin execution; the Java Virtual Machine calls
>   the run method of this thread.

[**How To Start a thread in java**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html)

Comment: @StreamMajor i recommend have a look at here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

Answer (score 3):

You are not supposed to call the run method yourself. Leave it to JVM. Use the start() method to call your run method. Your code is not creating a thread, instead its a sequential program